# Python type annotation for a value that can only be truth tested

Tags: python

Any Python object can be [truth tested](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), but is there a type annotation that indicates that the only thing you can do with an object is truth test it?

For example an implementation of `contains()` may look like this:

```py
def contains(xs: list[int], predicate: Callable[[int], bool]) -> bool:
  for x in xs:
    if predicate(x):
      return True
  return False
```

But the type annotation for `predicate` is overly restrictive since `if` can check for more things than just `bool`. You might have a predicate that returns `Optional[str]` and it would still work.

So what is the correct type to use for the return value of `predicate` instead of `bool`? It **isn't** `Any` because then you could accidentally do something like this:

```py
def contains(xs: list[int], predicate: Callable[[int], Any]) -> bool:
  for x in xs:
    if predicate(x).foo: # Whoops! Type checkers will allow this error.
      return True
  return False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `object` because all variables in Python are derived from `object`, and `object`s can be truth tested.

```py
def contains(xs: list[int], predicate: Callable[[int], object]) -> bool:
  for x in xs:
    if predicate(x):
      return True
  return False
```

Comment: The extend this (afaik correct answer) a little bit, the `object` annotation might be a little unintuitive to people who don't already know *why* that annotation was used ("of course, it takes `object`, everything is `object`"). The difference between technically correct and semantically meaningful. It may be worthwhile creating an alias, like `Truthy = object`, and using that.

Comment: Good point, although I guess it should be `Booly` rather than `Truthy`!

Comment: Or maybe `Truthiness`!